# Is it possible to do validation with regular expressions in a localized web application environment?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, localization, internationalization

Is it possible to do client side validation in a localized web application environment?

I've only seen regular expressions written in English, can they be written for other languages? Would the regular expressions have to be changed based on the language chosen by an end user or is it possible to use just 1?

Are there any tools/frameworks to help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answer was good, but it's not clear to me that it answered the question. For that matter, I don't really understand the question. If you're asking whether JavaScript regular expressions are independent of language, then the answer is yes, they are just looking at characters in a string. But obviously the things you're looking for with those regular expressions (words, numbers, phone numbers, dates, etc.) would presumably vary with language and locale. So you may be able to construct a universal regex that works to validate all phone numbers, for example, but it's probably unlikely, and in any case there may be cases where a valid number in one context is invalid in another. You're better off to create language-specific regular expressions used for validation just as you would create language specific strings. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Localisation really throws the cat among the pigeons when it comes to validation, especially for Anglosphere developers - we are so used to validating a string with an expression like /^[A-Z0-9\s]+/i that we forget what happens when John Le Carré wants to register an account and can't because his last name is invalid. Validating numbers, dates, phone numbers etc really do need locale-specific expressions - trying to create one true regex to validate all phone numbers is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Please do not confuse validation for well-formedness.  The former is a measure of conformity to a grammar definition and the later is a measure of conformity to a syntax requirement.  Even if your regex was so extremely awesome as to account for all well-formedness conditions it is absent the context of structured definitions where the structure is recursive and reflective.